# When I use [[]] as my index number, why does it return this?

Tags: python, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I'm a beginner in python so this might be a very dumb question:

So I was playing around with how people directly access an array.

I created an array `array = np.array([2,3,4])`

When I was trying to access it, instead of saying `print(array[1])`

I said `print(array[[1]])` and
it outputted `[3]` instead of just saying `3`.

Why is that? I think this could be related to how in dataframes people use `[[]]` to access categories but I'm not really sure about the connection here.

Also if possible, can someone please explain in simple terms what is the computer actually doing when people use `[[]]`.

I have tried to check the pandas documentation but I seriously don't understand it because I'm only a beginner in python.

Comment: this is a numpy thing. The `[[..]]` syntax allows you to get multiple elements out of the array. That's why you get back a list

Comment: Relevant documentation can be found [here](https://numpy.org/devdocs/user/basics.indexing.html#index-arrays).

Comment: Even without numpy, `[3]` is a list containing 3, and `[[3]]` is a list containing a list containing 3.  Both are useful in their contexts.

Comment: It's called "indexing".

Comment: @TimRoberts erm, no, in the context of indexing, `array[3]` is equivalent to `array.__getitem__(3)`, whereas `array[[3]]` is equivalent to `array.__getitem__([3])`

Comment: In any case, indexing with a sequence will always return an array in numpy (aside possibly from weird degenerate edge cases). Indexing with an integer will return an array if it has multiple dimensions, or a scalar if the array has one dimension

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga  I did say "without numpy", where what I said is quite correct.

Comment: @TimRoberts the issue isn't numpy, it's that in the syntactical context of indexing, that outer square bracket is not part of the expression being passed into the underlying method

Comment: In a `pandas` dataframe, `df['A']` returns a Series, column of the frame.  `df[['A']]` returns a dataframe with one column.  `df[['A','B']]]` returns a frame with 2 columns.  So yes, there is a similarity.  In both cases indexing with a list is different from indexing with a single index or column name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing there is extracting an array of elements from the array rather than just a single element. It just happens that you are getting an array of length one.

To understand better, try this:

```py
import numpy as np
a = np.array([2,3,4])
print(a[1])
print(a[2])
print(a[[1]])
print(a[[1,2,0,2,1]])
```

You should get

```
3
4
array([3])
array([3,4,2,4,3])
```

and hopefully you can see that the `[[1]]` case that you've tried is just a special case of the last example that I've added.

If that's still not clear, perhaps you could try this:

```py
a = np.array([2,3,4])
indices = [1,2,0,2,1]
print(a[indices])
```

which is the same thing, but might look more sensible to you. It's the difference between asking for the value at an index and asking for the values at a collection of indices. Both are possible with numpy.

Note also that this functionality is specific to numpy (and pandas), and does not work on regular Python lists:

```py
a = [2,3,4]
print(a[1])  # => 3
print(a[[1]])  # => TypeError
```